# How to make array in comma seperator string in php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have input in view laravel like below add more functionality.

```
<input type="text" name="batch_numbers[1]numbers">
```

I have variable of array. Want to make that array to string using comma seperator.

```
$variable = array:[
0 => array:1 [
"numbers" => "TS-001-0005"
]
1 => array:1 [
"numbers" => "TS-001-0006"
]
2 => array:1 [
"numbers" => "TS-001-0007"
]
3 => array:1 [
"numbers" => "TS-001-0008"
]
4 => array:1 [
"numbers" => "TS-001-0009"
]
]
```

Need to do this array in below format. tring using implode function but

```
TS-001-0005,TS-001-0006,TS-001-0007,TS-001-0008,TS-001-0009
```

If anyone have idea how to do this please let me know.

Comment: You already asked this question earlier today: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74030778/impode-the-array-element-like-string-with-comma-seperator. This looks like a duplicate, with no additional information; why are you expecting this one to not get downvoted and/or closed?

Comment: @TimLewis added the input type in view

Comment: That doesn't really help that much... Your last question at least showed your code attempts, but you were asked for more information on that question, and opted to delete your question instead. That's fine, but if you're going to ask the same question, you need to provide more useful information, or it will be downvoted and closed, just as the other one was.

Comment: @TimLewis actually i was stuck thats the reason create this question

Comment: That's fine; we all get stuck, but posting the exact same question without even really attempting to provide more information is not a great way to get help... When people on Stackoverflow ask you for more clarification/information, provide it, otherwise no one will be able (or willing) to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve using the [flatten](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-array-flatten) and the [join](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-array-join) methods provided by Laravel framework, this way:

Import:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
```

Then:

```
Arr::join(Arr::flatten($variable), ',')
```

Explanation:

`Arr::flatten` will return a new single level array from multi level array by removing all the keys except values. While, `Arr::join` will return a string, joining all the array elements/values separated by a `comma ,`.

Output:

```
TS-001-0005,TS-001-0006,TS-001-0007,TS-001-0008,TS-001-0009
```

Answer (score 0):

So, in your last question, you attempted to use `PHP`'s `implode()` function. This is fine, but doesn't work well on nested arrays. In your case, you don't need a nested Array:

```
<input type="text" name="batch_numbers[0]"/>
<input type="text" name="batch_numbers[1]"/>
<input type="text" name="batch_numbers[2]"/>
```

Given those inputs, to get a CSV of their values, you can simply use:

```
$csv = implode(',', $request->input('batch_numbers'));
```

Proper nested inputs would be:

```
<input type="text" name="batch_numbers[0]['numbers']"/>
<input type="text" name="batch_numbers[1]['numbers']"/>
<input type="text" name="batch_numbers[2]['numbers']"/>
```

To `implode()` this, you'd need a different method, maybe something like:

```
$csv = implode(',', array_column($request->input('batch_numbers'), 'numbers')));
```